# Is there a way to force refresh `current_user` in Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-login

As we know, any additional columns added to the Users table (by extension) get automatically pulled into `current_user` for easy retrieval in our Flask App.

I notice however that if I update a value in the database directly (or somehow externally to the Flask app itself) the value of `current_user` remains unchanged (it seems to update after a while but we're talking tens of minutes or longer... still testing).

The only way I can successfully refresh the data so far:

- server restart - not useful for real-world application
- update another value in the Users table (this time via the Flask App itself) - I'm using this as a temporary measure until a better solution is found but I don't like it, it feels really wrong

**Is there a command that I can call?** I've not managed to find anything so far in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine your `user_loader` function and `login_user()` to reload the user object and log it in, refreshing the `current_user` object. e.g.

```
def reload_current_user():
  user = load_user(current_user.id)
  login_user(user)
```

This could then be used in views as you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work